# Why do I get "undefined method `start_with?'"?

Tags: ruby

I get:

```
undefined method 'start_with?' for "-f":String (NoMethodError)
```

At this line:

```
if arg.start_with?("-v")
```

This worked on a different machine apparently so I'm assuming it could be a problem with my Ruby installation. Any ideas?

Comment: +1 for self-diagnosing that it was a Ruby installation problem. Way too many questions on SO are from people who can't get that far.

Comment: Are you tying to parse command line arguments? Use `optparse` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`String#start_with?` was introduced in Ruby 1.8.7. You're apparently using an earlier version, which is (sadly) not uncommon, but the 1.8 series *is* being retired shortly and you should considering upgrading.

I can't find any reference to `String#start_with?` in the [1.8.6 docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-start_with-3F), but it exists in the [1.8.7 docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-start_with-3F).

Comment: You should upgrade ASAP, 1.8.x is no longer supported and no longer receives security fixes (1.8.5 has not been updated in years). Upgrade to Ruby 1.9 or preferably 2.0.

Comment: How to upgrade depends on what OS. If the Ruby you're using came pre-installed, I'd leave it alone and install RVM or rbenv to manage new versions in a sandbox if you're using Linux or Mac OS. That way you can install multiple Rubies and switch between them easily. It's a much better way to go.

Comment: I did upgrade to 1.9.3 and unsurprisingly enough the error is now gone. Thank you!